# Access ansible playbook results after run of playbook

Tags: python, automation, ansible

I am running an ansible script using `ansible-pull` on a remote machine(client side)  which I can't see .

I want to make sure that :

- ansible playbook are executed successfully then should send summary
- ansible playbook if not executed successfully should send summary of what failed

Enabling ansible logs store information in some log file but was wondering if I can get the results of below ansible output via some variables predefined in ansible.

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Install the hello package] ********************************************* 
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false}

TASK: [Install the cmatrix package] ******************************************* 
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

If not then I will have to write the custom scripts to parse the logs , save information in some db on machine and send it back to our servers .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK there is no variable where you could just get this data from.

But this screams for a [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins). Have a look at the plugin [`community.general/plugins/callback/log_plays.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/callback/log_plays.py). It writes its own logfile. You could intercept all the messages, collect them and at the end (define a method `def playbook_on_stats(self, stats):` in your plugin) do with it whatever you want. There also is the [`community.general/plugins/callback/mail.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/callback/mail.py) which will send emails on failed tasks.

Comment: Thanks . Using this log_plays(https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-1.9/plugins/callbacks/log_plays.py) . However I just simply tried to log the stats variable in `def playbook_on_stats(self, stats)` this function. My code was one line -- `log(host, 'STATISTICS' , stats )`. Wondering its not at all being called

Comment: I can ofcourse use other fucntions which are working but wondering why stats function is not being called ?