# Is there a way to print only Ansible PLAY RECAP into CSV or HTML file and mail it?

Tags: ansible

We have the use case to print only Ansible playbook recap for bulk deployment on say 50+ servers and send the results in mail with attachment in CSV format.

Other scenario is to print whole playbook output and download it inCSV format into a NAS share.

We can print task results into CSV file but no playbook recap and entire playbook results in Ansible.

Please advice if anybody did it?

Comment: Have you already tried [some of the callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list), are you aware of [Ara](https://ara.recordsansible.org/), and have you already looked into [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme) or Tower?

Comment: I am looking at  Tower API called Job Host Summaries resource that provides similar information to the play recap. I am not aware of Ara

Answer (score 0):

Since the environment and setup isn't further described and also the requirement is very vague, it is assumed you are just running `ansible-playbook ...` from CLI and [send the output to `STDOUT`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html).

In such case you could use commands like

```
ansible-playbook deployment.yml | tee deployment.log
sed -n '/PLAY RECAP/,$p' deployment.log
```

and proceed further from there.

**Thanks to**

- [Linux - `grep` from certain lines to the end of file](https://superuser.com/questions/1033413/)

Regarding an own plugin, you may take advantage from Ansible Issue #[14367](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14367) "*Show aggregated playbook execution recap at the bottom of play recap*" or [Access Ansible playbook results after run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798251/).