# How to save only the play recap of Ansible to a file?

Tags: ansible

The question is as the title said, how to save only the "play recap" of ansible to a file or variable?

I am trying to make a web UI using Flask to make the user use ansible easier without writing any script or playbook, just write some hosts' IP address and click on what you want to do and flask/python script will call and play the premade playbook. The problem is I can't really tell the user whether the task is successfully done or not, because it only shows on Linux terminal. Therefore I want to "catch" only the "play recap" of the playbook and show it on a web page to tell the user the result.

Comment: What i have done to display the results of execution of playbook is that, i have save the logs in database with the ID of specific server, and they displayed the logs on UI by fetching them from DB. one can easily grep the results and status of tasks executed during the whole playbook.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't re-inventing [AWX (aka Tower)](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme)? Or, if you insist on running it by hand, [ARA](https://ara.recordsansible.org/) may interest you

Comment: See [Plugin list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html?highlight=output%20plugin#plugin-list). You'll have to write a [plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Since the environment and setup isn't further described, it is assumed you are just running `ansible-playbook ...` from CLI and [send the output to `STDOUT`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html).

In such case you could use commands like

```
ansible-playbook deployment.yml | tee deployment.log
sed -n '/PLAY RECAP/,$p' deployment.log
```

and proceed further from there.

**Thanks to**

- [Linux - `grep` from certain lines to the end of file](https://superuser.com/questions/1033413/)
- [Is there a way to print only Ansible PLAY RECAP into CSV or HTML file and mail it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029272/)

Regarding an own plugin, you may take advantage from Ansible Issue #[14367](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14367) "*Show aggregated playbook execution recap at the bottom of play recap*" or [Access Ansible playbook results after run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798251/).